# Auto attach to forked process in CLion for debugging

Tags: debugging, rust, clion

I'm using CLion to develop a combined C / Rust program. The program spins off a number of processes that I need to debug. The normal way to do it is to start the main process, have it fork a process, then manually click Run / Attach to Process, search for the forked process, click it and then everything works fine.

This is slow and tedious. Is it possible to set an option somewhere that will automatically attach to a named process?

I'm using LLDB on a Mac.